# How to combine query results as new columns?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

I have a table which consist of 200 different sensor and corresponding sensor value. I would like to create a query where different sensor values are in different columns.

I already tried join and union it doesnt give as expected.

Select * from measuredValue; // simplified

---

> | sensorId  | Value  |
>
> | 6         | 110    |
>
> | 6         | 120    |

| 6         | 180    |

| 8         | 250    |

| 8         | 280    |

| 8         | 290    |

---

goal

> > ---
> >
> > | sensor6  | sensor8|
> >
> > | 110          | 250    |
> >
> > | 120      | 280    |
> >
> > | 180      | 290    |
> >
> > ---

PS:rows for sensor are always equal. there is also timestamp column in the table. i thought it was irrelevant to put in here.

Comment: Humm this makes no sense to me... What if a sensor id was say `4678771`... you're supposed to **know** the column name you want data from, you're trying instead to do guesswork over *N* columns . How should one know the possible columnID numbers? I rather think that, you're after on how to represent the first table data into an UI in a different way. Which should be pretty straightforward, by using JS or any other language.

Answer (score 0):

You can join on the timestamp. Let's say your sensors save measures every hour. You can

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(sensor6.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d-%H'), 
    sensor6.value as sensor6, 
    sensor8.value as sensor8
FROM
    sensorMeasures sensor6
JOIN
    sensorMeasures sensor8 ON 
        DATE_FORMAT(sensor6.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d-%H') = 
        DATE_FORMAT(sensor8.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d-%H')
WHERE 
    sensor6.sensorId = 6
    AND sensor8.sensorId = 8
```

By joining on the timestamp, you will get a table of lines that contains all couples of sensor data from the same date/time.
The two where clauses simply select the right lines (where the first sensor data is from the 6th sensor and the second sensor data is from the 8th).

Of course, you can change the DATE_FORMAT format to match the frequency at which data is stored in that database.

Comment: What if you dynamically want to change the ID or the number of the sensors you're interested in? Not sure if that's OP intention but the above hardcodes and aims specifically towards two specific ones.

Comment: You could build a stored procedured like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135650/how-to-make-row-values-to-column-dynamically-in-mysql?answertab=active#tab-top .

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan My solution names the temporary tables `sensor6` and `sensor8` for clarity, but they could really be called `firstSensor` and `secondSensor`, with the `WHERE` clause being of course dynamic, so there is no actual hard-coding in the proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

my solution is based on the idea that there is a ranking to alle the sensor value.
The data to stest it

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(`sensorId` int, `Value` int)
;

INSERT INTO table1
(`sensorId`, `Value`)
VALUES
(6, 110),
(6, 120),
(6, 180),
(8, 250),
(8, 280),
(8, 290),
 (9, 250),
(9, 280),
(9, 290)
;
```

And then i used this query

```
Select Value6,Value8,Value9 
From
 (SELECT   Value as Value6,
      @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
  FROM      table1 t1, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
  Where sensorId =6
  ORDER BY  Value) t1
inner join
  (SELECT   Value as Value8,
      @curRank2 := @curRank2 + 1 AS rank
  FROM      table1 t2, (SELECT @curRank2 := 0) r
  Where sensorId =8
  ORDER BY  Value) t2 on t1.rank = t2.rank
inner join
  (SELECT   Value as Value9,
      @curRank3 := @curRank3 + 1 AS rank
  FROM      table1 t2, (SELECT @curRank3 := 0) r
  Where sensorId =9
  ORDER BY  Value) t3 on t1.rank = t3.rank;
```

The result

```
Value6  Value8  Value9
 110    250     250
 120    280     280
 180    290     290
```

This relys that there are  always the same number of rows per sensorId.
This can also be used in a stored procedure like i done it here
[how to make row values to column dynamically in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135650/how-to-make-row-values-to-column-dynamically-in-mysql?answertab=active#tab-top)
But here you don't need the cursor only the loop From 1 to 200.

To be honest i would ose a single select * From table1 order By SensorId, Value, and use the result in jquer.success.

Comment: The author said there is a `timestamp` column in the tables, so it's better to use it as it is less reliable to base the query on the `rank` than on the `timestamp`. One sensor might have started to record values earlier, in which case there won't be the same number of rows from the different sensors. With the join based on timestamp, you can be sure that the values returned on the same line were taken at the same time. But maybe the author should specify which behavior he expects : should the final result be based solely on the number of results, or on the time at which values were recorded?

Comment: i found your answer very good and i thought about it, but without any information about the timestamp, it is a solution that works.